# App.xaml file does not get parsed if my app does not set a StartupUri?

Tags: wpf, xaml, resources, startup

Background: I'm creating a WPF app using MVVM, and using a DI container to build my ViewModels

My App.xaml looks like this:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApp.App"
    ...xmlns etc...
    StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <app:ServiceLocator x:Key="serviceLocator" />
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

MainWindow.xaml looks like this:

```
<Window x:Class="CompositeMefWpfApp.MainWindow"
    ...xmlns etc... >
    <Control.DataContext>
        <Binding Path="MainWindowViewModel" Source="{StaticResource serviceLocator}" />
    </Control.DataContext>
```

Now, this all works fine, but the `StartupUri` is hardcoded into the XAML, which I don't want.
Following guidance of several blogposts and articles I found, I removed the `StartupUri`, and tried to create the `MainWindow` by hooking `OnStartup` in App.xaml.cs, like this:

```
protected override void OnStartup( StartupEventArgs e )
{
    base.OnStartup(e);
    new MainWindow().Show();
}
```

The problem is, the app crashes when trying to show the window, with this exception:

> Cannot find resource named '{serviceLocator}'. Resource names are case sensitive.  Error at object 'System.Windows.Data.Binding' in markup file 'WpfApp;component/mainwindow.xaml' Line 8 Position 45.

As far as I can tell, the `<Application.Resources>` section is simply not being read out of the xaml file. I can put some code in the OnStartup to add the resource programatically like this:

```
Resources.BeginInit();
Resources.Add("serviceLocator", new ServiceLocator());
Resources.EndInit();
```

However that's an ugly hack, and doesn't help me if I wanted to put something else in the app.xaml file later on :-(

Should I be hooking some other event? Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Rather than overriding OnStartup, try using an event instead:

```
<Application x:Class="My.App"
    xmlns="..."
    Startup="Application_Startup"
    ShutdownMode="OnExplicitShutdown">
        <Application.Resources>
            <app:ServiceLocator x:Key="serviceLocator" />
        </Application.Resources>
    </Application>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    { }
    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: Parse commandline arguments and other startup work 
        new MainWindow().Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is it important to set up event from xaml? It fails if set up from constructor...

Comment: Beware that PRISM application have this problem by default. Solved by adding empty event Application_Startup.

Answer (score 27):

The most simple workaround is the definition of a **x:Name**:

```
<Application x:Name="App" ...
    <Application.Resources>
        ...
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

More information: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/472729/wpf-cannot-find-resource-defined-in-the-app-xaml-file

Comment: the link is broken. Can't even find issue through the search

Comment: Added new one https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/772087/

Comment: This solution has worked for me and it is the simplest.

Comment: This helped me a lot. Thanks :)

Comment: Both links are broken.

Answer (score 13):

I've run into a  similar/this same issue. There's a VS code generation bug where the code necessary to connect `<Application.Resources>` to the rest of the program sometimes is not inserted when `<Application.Resources>` contains only one entry and  does not have a `StartupUri` attribute.

Details: 
http://bengribaudo.com/blog/2010/08/19/106/bug-single-application-resources-entry-ignored *(disclaimer--link points to my blog)*

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 still has the bug :-( Another three hours of my life gone there.

Comment: This error happens sometimes in production with an app I developed in VS 2017. So it appears the bug is still present.

Comment: Late 2020 and the problem is still there. An empty Startup="Application_Startup" event handler on the <Application ... did the trick for me. Feels a little clunky though.

Answer (score 2):

To get around this know bug you can also just add resources programmatically.

```
var rd = new ResourceDictionary()
rd.Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources;component/Colors.xaml");
Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(rd);
```

This code can be placed inside the construtor for the `App` class.