# How to customize startup of WPF application?

Tags: wpf, startup

When a new WPF Application project is created, `MainWindow.xaml`, `App.xaml` and their corresponding code behind classes are automatically generated. In the `App.xaml` there is an attribute that defines which window is going to be run initially and by default, it's `StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"`

I have created a new `Dispatcher` class in the same project. At startup, I want the instance of that class `Dispatcher` to be constructed and then one of its method to run. That method would actually create and show the `MainWindow` window. So how do I modify the `App.xaml` or `App.xaml.cs` in order to make it happen? Or, if it cannot be done by `App`, how should I implement it? Thanks.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can remove the `StartupUri` attribute from the App.xaml.

Then, by creating an override for `OnStartup()` in the App.xaml.cs, you can create your new instance of your `Dispatcher` class.

Here's what my quick app.xaml.cs implementation looks like:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
      base.OnStartup(e);

      new MyClassIWantToInstantiate();
    }
  }
}
```

**Update**

I recently discovered [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3896209/23074) for a bug if you use this method to customize app startup and suddenly none of the Application-level resources can be found.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use the Startup event (class Application) - [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.startup.aspx).

You can show MainWindow in this event handler - after you create a Dispatcher instance.

Answer (score 1):

1.In App.xaml,  To replace the StartupUri with a subscription to the Startup event.

2. Use the event in App.xaml.cs .

For instance,

Startup="Application_Startup" in .xaml.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        // Create the startup window
        MainWindow wnd = new MainWindow();
        // Do stuff here, e.g. to the window
        wnd.Title = "Something else";
        // Show the window
        wnd.Show();
    }
}
```