# Why are Application-Resources only loaded when placed in a seperate file if OnStartup is overriden?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

In App.xaml (**no StartupUri**):

```
...
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="AppResources.xaml"/>
</Application.Resources>
...
```

This does work but declaring the `ResourceDictionary` directly in `Application.Resources` does not:

```
...
<Application.Resources >
    <ResourceDictionary>
        ...
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
...
```

OnStartup in App.xaml.cs:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        if (e.Args.Length > 0)
        {
            // Handle args and start headless.
        }
        else
        {
            // Create window.
            new Views.ShellWindow().ShowDialog();
        }
        this.Shutdown();
    }
```

How can this behaviour be fixed?

Edit: I am using Visual Studio 2013 Professional.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't replicate your situation in Visual Studio 2010. What version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there is a VS code generation bug where the code necessary to connect  to the rest of the program sometimes is not inserted when

- The application has no StartupUri attribute set in App.xaml AND
- there is only one resoure in the  section of App.xaml

A possible workaround is to use an event instead of overriding OnStartup, see [WPF - App.xaml file does not get parsed if my app does not set a StartupUri?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543414/wpf-app-xaml-file-does-not-get-parsed-if-my-app-does-not-set-a-startupuri) for more information.