# XAML ResourceDictionary not loading correctly with a single keyset

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I've been working on a WPF application and have come across some rather strange behavior concerning resources defined in the `Application.Resources` element of my App.XAML file.

I really only need a single string resource defined in my ResourceDictionary, and I attempted this with the following XAML:

```
<Application x:Class="MyClass.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <Application.Resources>
        <sys:String x:Key="htmlHelpFilePath">.\Help\glossary.chm</sys:String>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

And then attempted to access it with the following code:

```
ResourceDictionary resourceDictionary = App.Current.Resources;
string htmlHelpFile = (string)resourceDictionary["htmlHelpFilePath"];
```

This unfortunately resulted in `htmlHelpFile` being set to null. The debugger also revealed that `resourceDictionary` had zero keysets.

I started to play around and found that simply adding another resource into my `Application.Resource` XAML element allows for the dictionary to properly populate, so I ended up settling with:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <sys:String x:Key="htmlHelpFileName">glossary.chm</sys:String>
    <sys:String x:Key="htmlHelpFileDirectory">.\Help\</sys:String>
</Application.Resources>
```

This solution is works as expected and I have moved on with my work, but I am absolutely mystified by why this is behavior is occurring in the way that its occurring. My knowledge about the inner workings of XAML configured WPF applications is very basic, and would love to know the reason for this bizarre behavior.

Comment: How do you retrieve resources in second case?

Comment: @Sinatr yes, when I attempted to access resources with the two included, I was receiving the expected strings in the actual C# code

Comment: Which .NET Framework version are you using?

Comment: @IIVic I'm using (and am restricted to) 3.5 for this project

Comment: No mystery there. It was just a bug (which i guess has been fixed by now) See here: https://www.bengribaudo.com/blog/2010/08/19/106/bug-single-application-resources-entry-ignored  and here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/772087/ (i am not sure if providing two links would count as answer (; )

Comment: @elgonzo thank you! I'd be happy to accept this as an answer if you post it and elaborate a bit (like the technical details of the first link). If not I'll do that myself, but since you found it, you're of course entitled to the reputation!

Comment: Yeah, the reputation... and the labor. No, jk. I'll write up an answer :) By the way, i checked the Microsoft Connect issue again -- it is closed as a 'won't fix'... :(

Comment: By the way, i'll flag your question as a duplicate of the other question i linked in my answer. Nothing against you, just for SO housekeeping ;)

Comment: @elgonzo totally valid, I won't contest!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug. Ben Gribaudo wrote on his blog about this issue ([link to full blog post](https://www.bengribaudo.com/blog/2010/08/19/106/bug-single-application-resources-entry-ignored)). Quoting the relevant bits from this post:

> [...]
>
> In the program’s App.xaml file:
>
> - The <Application> tag **does not have a StartupUri attribute**. (Instead, the program’s initial window is launched by an override of
>     Application’s OnStartup method in App.xaml.cs.)
> - <Application.Resources> contains **only one entry**.
>
> [...]
>
> Visual Studio auto-generates a hidden file named App.g.cs which “wires” App.xaml into the application. When the above-mentioned two factors are present, **the code generator sometimes fails to insert the code that loads <Application.Resources>’s contents into the application**. If this loading does not occur, other XAML files in the program will be unable to use the resources defined in <Application.Resources>.

(emphasis mine)

Microsoft Connect also has a record of this issue ([link](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/772087/)); however the responsible development team has declared it as a "won't fix".

There is also a StackOverflow question with a number of answers discussing different possible workarounds: [App.xaml file does not get parsed if my app does not set a StartupUri?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543414/app-xaml-file-does-not-get-parsed-if-my-app-does-not-set-a-startupuri)

One workaround you discovered already by yourself -- avoid having just a single resource in the resource dictionary by simply adding a second (dummy) resource.

Comment: Thanks for posting this, bummer about the "won't fix" status though.. :/

Comment: Well, considering that workarounds are simple and numerous, the risks of a bug fix potentially breaking other things and the efforts needed to implement it were perhaps not justified in the eye of the development team, i guess. Still, it would have been nice if at least the VS team would have provided some checker that warns if it finds those specific conditions in a project.